# Qt (C++) log gets filled with "Widget (address) does not have a property named (var)"

Tags: c++, qt

When running the program in Qt Creator, the console log gets filled with messages that say...

```
QMenu(0x21aef3db1c0) does not have a property named "myVar"
```

I have only **main.cpp**, **mainwindow.cpp/h**. I'm using Q_PROPERTY in mainwindow.

**mainwindow.cpp**

```
MainWindow::MainWindow(QWidget *parent)
    : QMainWindow(parent)
{
    // code here
}

QColor MainWindow::getMyVar() const
{
    return myVar;
}

void MainWindow::setMyVar(QColor c)
{
    myVar = c;
}

MainWindow::~MainWindow()
{
}
```

**mainwindow.h**

```
#ifndef MAINWINDOW_H
#define MAINWINDOW_H

#include <QMainWindow>

class MainWindow : public QMainWindow
{
    Q_OBJECT
    Q_PROPERTY(QColor myVar READ getMyVar WRITE setMyVar DESIGNABLE true)

public:
    MainWindow(QWidget *parent = 0);
    ~MainWindow();
    QColor getMyVar() const;
    void setMyVar(QColor c);
private:
    QColor myVar;
};

#endif // MAINWINDOW_H
```

**stylesheet.qss**

```
* {
    qproperty-myVar: red;
}
```

What's the point of this message and what can I do to get rid of it?

Comment: Are you sure that is all your code? You have declared the destructor in the .h, but I do not see the implementation in the .cpp. I recommend you delete the build folder and recompile.

Comment: @eyllanesc I've updated the post, the destructor was in cpp, I just didn't paste it here for some reason. I've done a clean, qmake and rebuild which hasn't helped.

Comment: The error message appears to come from the `Qt` style sheet code.  Are you using a style sheet anywhere that refers to `myVar` in the context of a `QMenu`?

Comment: @G.M. I'm loading an external style sheet file from main. I'm coming from Visual Studio to Qt IDE and I don't remember seeing this error. But it completely spams and fills up console log in Qt, it will print the message for each widget in the program, so the list gets very big.

Comment: How big is the style sheet?  If not too big then please edit your question to show it if possible.

Comment: @G.M. Very small, this is a test program so I can try figure out what's wrong. I edited the post with info.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `*` in your stylesheet rule matches everything:

```
* {
    qproperty-myVar: red;
}
```

This means that this style will be applied to all widgets, not just your `MainWindow` widget. For example, it will be applied to the `QMenu` of your main window, and Qt complains here that `QMenu` does not have a `myVar` property -- indeed it does not!

Try the following instead:

```
MainWindow {
    qproperty-myVar: red;
}
```